# First Dimension Unsized Class Member

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, static, dynamic-arrays, member-variables

I have a class I'm converting:

```
class MyClass
{
public::
    void foo( void )
    {
        static const char* bar[][3] = { NULL };
        func( bar );
    }
};
```

Now I want to make bar a member variable, but because the first dimension is unsized I can't. I also can't pass `const char** bar[3]` to `void func( const char* param[][3] )`. Is there a workaround for this that I'm unaware of, or is this a situation where I must use a method `static`?

**Edit in Response to [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42)**

Matching the initialization of `bar` is my problem here. I think I should at least be able to accomplish this in the ctor body, if not the ctor initialization list. Here's some test code:

```
static const char* global[][3] = { NULL };

void isLocal( const char* test[][3] )
{
    // This method outputs" cool\ncool\nuncool\n
    if( test == NULL )
    {
        cout << "uncool" << endl;
    }
    else if( *test[0] == NULL )
    {
        cout << "cool" << endl;
    }
}

class parent
{
public:
    virtual void foo( void ) = 0;
};

parent* babyMaker( void )
{
    class child : public parent
    {
    public:
        virtual void foo( void )
        {
            static const char* local[][3] = { NULL };

            isLocal( local );
            isLocal( global );
            isLocal( national );
        }
        child():national( nullptr ){}
    private:
        const char* (*national)[3];
    };
    return new child;
}

int main( void )
{
    parent* first = babyMaker();
    first->foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const char* bar[][3]` is not `const char** bar[3]` but `const char* (*bar)[3]`.
So you may want something like:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : bar(nullptr) {}

    void foo() { func(bar); }
private:
    const char* (*bar)[3];
};
```

I suggest to use `typedef` as:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef const char* bar_t[3];
public:
    MyClass() : bar(new bar_t[2]) {
        for (int j = 0; j != 2; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
                bar[j][i] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
    ~MyClass() { delete [] bar; }

    void foo() { func(bar); }

private:
    MyClass(const MyClass&); // rule of three
    MyClass& operator =(const MyClass&); // rule of three
private:
    bar_t* bar;
};
```

or:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef const char* bar_t[3];
public:
    MyClass() { for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) { bar[0][i] = nullptr; } }

    void foo() { func(bar); }

private:
    bar_t bar[1];
};
```

Comment: You are right on the typing! however your initialization doesn't work. I was working on creating an initialization in the ctor body, but I don't think I properly understand what type this creates.

Comment: `nullptr` is C++11, you may use `NULL` instead.

Comment: I've dumped my test code into the question, and you can see that the local variable is initialized differently.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I have added sample to initialize `bar` (as wanted).

Comment: It appears that apart from declaring the variable with a defined size, my only recourse for initialization is a static variable :( I would like one further clarification, `const char* (*bar)[3]` doesn't define a size 3 array of `char**`s like I thought, but what does it define?

Comment: `bar` is a pointer of an array (of size 3) of `const char*`. In C++11, it is clearer: `std::array<const char*, 3>* bar`;

Comment: Is there a way that I can cast from `std::array< const char*, 3 >* bar` to the `const char* param[][3]` parameter of `func`? Or perhaps visa-verse, where the parameter is of type `std::array< const char*, 3 >*` and I cast to that from `const char* bar[][3]`?

Comment: @JonathanMee: You can cast `std::array< const char*, 3 >` into `const char* (*bar)[3]` (see https://ideone.com/VLvGrF)... Not sure it is the clean way to do...

Comment: Yikes `reinterpret_cast`, I know we've totally left the scope of the original question so I'll make a new question and post a link here. Thanks for your time. I think because the original member variable was static I have to make a static variable in the function's scope, but I still want an answer to the casting question.

Comment: The conversation continues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671635/cast-between-const-char-3-and-stdarray-const-char-3