# Cast between const char* [][3] and std::array< const char*, 3 >*

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I need a way to cast between these two types of variables:

```
std::array< const char*, 3 >* foo;
const char* foo[][3];
```

Because I need to be able to pass both types to a function. The function can be defined either of these ways, whichever makes conversion easier:

```
void bar( std::array< const char*, 3 >* param );
void bar( const char* param[][3] );
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538802/first-dimension-unsized-class-member) question, [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) suggests using the method [here](https://ideone.com/VLvGrF). Is there a cleaner way to do this?

**Edit in response to [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp)'s [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205186/treat-c-cstyle-array-as-stdarray/11205298#11205298)**

This `reinterpret_cast` did work for me, but [Ivan Shcherbakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306670/ivan-shcherbakov) describes it as an "ugly dirty hack" I've pasted the code, below... I don't understand why this is a hack, or why something could go wrong with it? Is the template method suggested by [Nathan Monteleone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27130/nathan-monteleone) necessarily better than this?

```
void bar( std::array< const char*, 3 >* param ){}

void main( void )
{
    static const char* cStyle[][3] = { NULL };
    std::array< const char*, 3 > foo = { NULL };
    std::array< const char*, 3 >* stlStyle = &foo;

    bar( reinterpret_cast< std::array< const char*, 3 >* >( cStyle ) );
    bar( stlStyle );
}
```

Comment: May we know what are you trying to store in `foo`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.. `std::array`'s size and alignment are not specified AFAIK, therefore a `std::array<X,Y>*` is not compatible to a `X (*arr)[Y]`

Comment: Related: [Treat C cstyle array as std::array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205186/treat-c-cstyle-array-as-stdarray)

Comment: You say that the function can be defined either of those ways, but *must* it be defined in one of those ways? With `template<class I> void bar(I start, I end)`, you can pass iterators to either of those containers or indeed any standard container or c-style array or just part of a container.

Comment: dyp, I think the point is that the alignment isn't specified, and yes, both versions of foo should be exactly compatible. black, This variable is going to contain 3 dynamically allocated arrays of c-strings.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?

Comment: @Jefffrey This is a simplification. Those dimensions are going to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: @JonathanMee, then why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: @JonathanMee, what does the algorithm `bar` do?

Comment: Also, do you know that `const char* [][3]` is a **bidimensional** array that contains C-strings, while `std::array< const char*, 3 >` is an **unidimensional** array that contains C-strings?

Comment: @Jefffrey The `bar` algorithm is a simplification of a mutator and getter function.

Comment: @JonathanMee, Could you please clarify what do you mean exactly by "mutator and getter function"?

Comment: @Jefffrey They're both bidimensional, it might be easier to see if I write the C-Style array like this: `const char* ( *foo )[3]`

Comment: @JonathanMee, `std::array< const char*, 3 >*` is a pointer to a **unidimensional** array. Are you saying that you are dynamically allocating an `std::array< const char*, 3 >` with `new[]`?

Comment: @Jefffrey A "pointer to a unidimensional array" that's what both `foo`s are. And a dynamically allocated "pointer to a unidimensional array" is by definition a bidimensional array.

Comment: @JonathanMee, What do those three strings in the `std::array< const char*, 3 >` represents in your application?

Comment: @Jefffrey If it wasn't clear that I'm doing something sketchy from my variables, it will be after I explain this: The c-strings are code that will be used dynamically.

Comment: @JonathanMee, what I mean is: can't you put those three strings in a `struct`?

Comment: Jefffrey, Clearly I _can_. But because I'm working within a preexisting code base, the best course of action would be to modernize my code to the greatest extent possible, while leaving the rest of the code base intact. I'm excited about the solution that Nathan Monteleone led me to, because it accomplishes that, without requiring me to modify code that I don't have the time to digest and then edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Nathan Monteleone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27130/nathan-monteleone)'s solution:

```
template<typename T>
enable_if_t<conditional_t<is_array_v<T>, extent<T>, tuple_size<T>>::value == 3U> bar(T* param){}
```

I believe this solution is the best of all worlds, cause it avoids the `reinterpret_cast` that is implementation dependent. And it enforces that `param` must be of size 3 at compile time.

Note that the `conditional_t`'s value is called only after a type is selected. For more on this see: [Short Circuiting Operators in an enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52079896/2642059)

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73d9360e4d1877a1)

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, the easiest most elegant thing you could do is just make your bar function a template.

```
template <class T> void Tbar( T param ) {
    char c12 = param[1][2];    // (for example)
}
```

Of course at that point you lose the ability to enforce that it be of size [3].  So you could do something like hide the template implementation down in a source file, expose both of your original functions as prototypes in a header, and in the cpp file just implement as

```
void bar( std::array< const char*, 3 >* param ) { Tbar(param); }
void bar( const char* param[][3] ) { Tbar(param); }
```

The advantage of this sort of approach is that it avoids casting entirely.  The disadvantage, I suppose, is that you're a little bit more limited in what you can do inside Tbar, namely you're restricted to whatever operations both `char*[][3]` and `array<char*, 3>*` have in common.  It would also be harder to store off a pointer to the array if, for example, Tbar was a setter in a non-template class.

Comment: I think I could do a `static_assert` with `extents` to ensure that the size was 3, right? Then I should be able to proceed with uniform instantiation.

Comment: @JonathanMee You might be able to.  I actually have never used `std::extent` before, so would like to know if you have any success with that.

Comment: Nathan Monteleone Well I had less success than I would have hoped for. I'm having trouble using `std::extent` on both an `std::array` and a C-style array. I'd like to make this work though cause according to Ivan Shcherbakov, I'm a bad person if I don't. To that end I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712965/using-stdextent-on-stdarray