# Type trait to get element type of std::array or C-style array

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I would like a type trait to get the element type of either a `std::array` or a plain old C-style array, eg. it should return `char` when provided with either `std::array<char, 3>` or `char[3]`.

The mechanisms to do this appear to be only partially in place... I can use `::value_type` on the `std::array`, and `std::remove_all_extents` on the plain array, but I can't find a single type trait that combines both and I'm unable to write one myself.

I've got as far as this:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
using element_type =  typename std::conditional<
    std::is_array<T>::value,
    typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type,
    typename T::value_type
>::type;
```

It works just fine for `std::array`, of course:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<char, element_type<std::array<char, 3>>>::value,
        "element_type failed");
}
```

but breaks when I pass it a plain array, because obviously plain arrays don't have a `::value_type`.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<char, element_type<char[3]>>::value, "element_type failed");
```

just gives errors like "*'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'*", as you'd expect.

If I were writing a function, I'd use `std::enable_if` to hide the offending template instantiation, but I don't see how this approach can be used in a type trait.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: std::remove_all_extents works for C arrays

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a *very* generic solution which supports any type of container/array supported by [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin):

```
template<typename T>
using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>;
```

`std::begin` as you may know returns an iterator. Dereferencing it gives you the value of it, which you can get the type of using `decltype`. The `std::remove_reference_t` is necessary because iterators return references to the element they are pointing at. As a result, this works for every single type for which `std::begin` has an overload.

Comment: I think you take the prize on this one, for that clever use of `std::begin`.

Comment: You can improve this a little bit.  There are some corner cases where the range-based for finds `begin/end` functions but this alias template won't. Define a function `auto begin_adl_helper(T && t){ using namespace std; return begin(t);}` and change your alias to use this function.  Then types which overload `begin` in a namespace other than std will work too.

Comment: @SirGuy Really? I always thought that ranged for uses begin and end internally. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I hit enter too soon on my comment, I had intended to explain myself in the same comment :P.  The difference is that range for loops use ADL when checking for a free function called `begin` where as your alias does not use ADL.  However, it seems that range-based for loops have a special handling of C-style arrays that allow them to work because `begin(c_array)` is not found via ADL.

Comment: @SirGuy Yes, true. `begin(c_array)` jus calls `std::begin`, nothing special. But does ADL really matter here? I mean, `std::begin` calls the member function `begin` if it exists. You don't need ADL like you would for say `std::swap`, which does not call any member function if it is not specialized.

Comment: Does ADL really matter here?  In practise I doubt it, 99.9% of the time somebody creating a custom range will add `begin/end` functions inside their class definition.  My point was that since you could make a change to make this type trait work in all cases that the range-based for works, I felt that you might as well.  Especially since you don't know who's going to come along and read this answer with their own crazy constraints getting in the way of a simpler solution.

Comment: @SirGuy It already works for every type that has begin/end functions. There is nothing to change. Let's say `Foo` has those 2 functions. Calling `std::begin(Foo{})` will call the custom member functions, because the only valid overload is the one taking a type and calling `begin` on it.

Answer (score 7):

What are the functions/operators you can call on both `std::array` and C-style arrays?  `operator[]` of course:

```
template <class Array>
using array_value_type = decay_t<decltype(std::declval<Array&>()[0])>;
```

This will work for anything that supports looking up by integer, including `std::vector`, `std::map<std::size_t, T>`, etc.

If you want to distinguish between what you get from a const array vs a non-cost array you might want to create 2 type traits named something along the lines of:

```
template <class Array>
using array_element_t = decay_t<decltype(std::declval<Array>()[0])>;

template <class Array>
using array_value_t   = remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<Array>()[0])>;
```

The second trait here preserves the constness of the `Array` type passed in while the first one strips it.  There are certainly use cases for both of these.

Comment: I very much like this approach, but I had to wrap it in a `std::remove_reference` in order to get something that I could work with (eg. pass the `static_assert` tests in the original question)

Comment: My previous comment was wrong: For containers with `const` elements, `std::decay` will strip the const out. `std::remove_reference_t` should be used instead, as it does not remove any cv-qualifiers.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That depends on whether the user wants a modifiable copy or wants to create a reference to it (where `decay_t` would then cause an error)

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this is to dispatch to specialized templates

```
template<typename>
struct arr_trait;

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct arr_trait<T[N]> {using type = T;};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct arr_trait<std::array<T, N>> {using type = T;};

template<typename T>
struct arr_trait<T&> : arr_trait<T> {};

template<typename T>
struct arr_trait<T&&> : arr_trait<T> {};

template<typename T>
using element_type = typename arr_trait<T>::type;
```

[Live](http://cpp.sh/8jmv6)

The reason `std::conditional` is failing is because it doesn't support (and neither can it as far as I know) support *short-circuiting*, and both types will be evaluated.

Comment: As it happens, I was just reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/22713242/1450890 and coming to the conclusion that I'd have to use the very approach you'd just suggested. Is it true to say that _no_ type trait can do the sort of short-circuiting I wanted?

Comment: @Rook As far as I know, nope

Comment: Also, thanks for reminding me of the `foo<T[N]>` syntax, which was a much better way to handle plain array template parameters than the ones I was messing with. Silly, because I've been reading the docs for using `unique_ptr` on plain arrays, which uses exactly that.