# How to differentiate two lambda functions by their return type?

Tags: c++, lambda, operator-overloading, c++17

i'm trying to create a bash-like pipe operator overload for lambda functions, in which you pass a vector and to a lambda that either filters or prints the vector

I've tried using auto with decltype, tried putting them all in the same function hoping auto would know when to return void and when to return the vector, but everything I try either doesn't compile or says ambiguous overload.

Here's the code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

void operator | ( auto& v, auto map ) {
  for( auto x : v )
    map( x );
}

template <typename T>
T operator | ( T& vet, auto map)  {
    cout << "else" << endl;
    T aux;
    for ( auto x : vet) 
        aux.push_back(x);
    return aux;
}

int main () {
    vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} ;
     v | []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } | [] ( int x ) { cout << x << endl; };
     v | [] ( int x ) { cout << x << endl; };
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what happens:

```
trabapply3.cc:25:6: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator|’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘main()::<lambda(int)>’)
   25 |    v | [] ( int x ) { cout << x << endl; };
```

Any tips?

Comment: "*`void operator | ( auto& v, auto map )`*" This isn't legal in C++17. It'll be legal in C++20, but it's not in C++17. Also, it's generally not a good idea to 1) globally overload an operator on unconstrained types, 2) override an operator in a way that does not do what the operator says it does, and 3) do both at the same time.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just curious, would creating a type called `pipe_wrapper<T>` that wraps around an iterable object and only specialize the operator function template for `pipe_wrapper` a better practice? Example call would be `wrap_pipe(object) | ... | ...`. (Or concerning the operator idiom rule `wrap_pipe(object).map(...).map(...)`). The latter looks like C# `IEnumerable.Select`

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::is_invocable_r`/`std::invoke_result_t`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>;

template <typename T, typename MapFunc, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<MapFunc, element_type_t<T>>>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
void operator | (const T& v, MapFunc&& map ) {
  for(auto&& x : v )
    map( x );
}

template <typename T, typename MapFunc, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<element_type_t<T>, MapFunc, element_type_t<T>>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
T operator | (const T& vet, MapFunc&& map)  {
    T aux;
    for (auto&& x : vet) 
        aux.push_back(map(x));
    return aux;
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} ;
     v | []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } | [] ( int x ) { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
     v | []( int x ) { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/33zSMBubghwEt4EF

note: about `element_type_t`: watch [Type trait to get element type of std::array or C-style array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521991/type-trait-to-get-element-type-of-stdarray-or-c-style-array)

BTW, you should not write `using namespace std;`.